# In what order does git apply file modifications when merging?

Tags: git, git-merge

Let's say I made several modifications in a file and I keep them in my local repository. Another developer also made several changes on the same file in his/her local repository and pushed them to central. So let's say I have commits A1 and A2 and he has commits B1 and B2. Chronologically they go as A1, B1, A2, B2.

In what order does git apply changes when merging? I.e. does it view the other developer's changes as one change, or does it apply them chronologically and takes into account the chronology of my own changes too?

Answer (score 4):

For a merge, it would be all changes viewed as one, and merge to your branch when you `git pull`.

But, should you `git pull --rebase`, then it would be A1, then A2 that would be merged on top of B1 and B2.

Comment: To add to this answer, git only considers the state of the branches at their tips (the final commit), and doesn't even consider any of the intermediate commits during the [3-way merge algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(revision_control)#Recursive_three-way_merge).